# Is $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ a groupoid $C^*$-algebra?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, groupoids

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a complex Hilbert space, and $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ be the $C^{\ast}$-algebra of bounded operators on $\mathcal{H}$. Is there an étale groupoid $\mathcal{G}$ such that its $C^{\ast}$-algebra (full or reduced) is isomorphic to $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$?

In [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.04105) paper, Alcides Buss and Aidan Sims proved that not all $C^{\ast}$-algebras are groupoid algebras. Note that $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ satisfies the criteria given in their paper.

A weaker form of this question is the following: Is every $C^{\ast}$-algebra a closed $\ast$-subalgebra of an étale groupoid $C^{\ast}$-algebra?

---

Edit: In discussion with Prof. Ruy Exel, he suggested some improvements to this question: Let $D \subseteq \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ be the $\ast$-subalgebra consisting of all diagonal operators relative to some orthonormal basis.

He advised me to specialize this question by demanding that the étale groupoid $\mathcal{G}$, with $C^{\ast}_{\mathrm{red}}(\mathcal{G}) \cong \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$, satisfies that the isomorphism induces a correspondence between $D$ and $C(\mathcal{G}^{(0)})$.

His suggestion is based on the fact that most of the time, when someone is tasked with finding a groupoid such that its reduced algebra is a specific $C^{\ast}$-algebra $A$, one specifies the subalgebra that corresponds to $C(\mathcal{G}^{(0)})$.

Comment: When you speak of "the" Cstar algebra of a groupoid - do you mean full? reduced?

Comment: Full or reduced. Edited. @YemonChoi

Comment: Are you sure $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ is not isomorphic to its opposite algebra? Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: It is isomorphic to its opposite algebra. This is why it might be a grupoid $C^*$-algebra.

Comment: @DiegoMartinez Very interesting! Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: Actually, let me rephrase my previous comment:

Ah, so you mean B(H) does not satisfy the criteria in that paper. In any case, the answer to your question may be "yes". The easiest that comes to mind is taking N with the distance d(n,m)=1 when n≠m. It then follows that the uniform Roe algebra of that space is B(ℓ2(N).

Comment: While the above is true, it is not true that the above model yields a Cartan subalgebra, since $\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N})$ is not a (C*-)Cartan subalgebra of $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{\ell^2(\mathbb{N}}))$, as it lacks enough normalizers. So I do not know the answer to your question. You may check Section 6.4 in my https://arxiv.org/pdf/2312.08907.pdf, where we do actually need local finiteness of the space to get a groupoid model.

Comment: @DiegoMartinez Great! Do you have some reference proving that the uniform Roe algebra of the natural numbers with the discrete metric is B(l^2(X))?

Comment: Well, by the very definition of what it means to be of finite propagation. $t \in \mathcal{B}(\ell^2(\mathbb{N}))$ has propagation at most $r \geq 0$ if $p_B t p_A = 0$ whenever $d(A, B) > r$. Since the space $(\mathbb{N}, d)$ is bounded, every operator has finite propagation (has propagation at most $1$). Hence $C_u^*(\mathbb{N}, d) = \mathcal{B}(\ell^2(\mathbb{N}))$.