$\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ as the reduced $C^*$-algebra of a groupoid
Given an infinite dimensional Hilbert Space $\mathcal{H}$ what is the underlying locally compact Hausdorff etale groupoid $G$ such that $C_r^{\ast}(G)$ is $\ast$-isomorphic to $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ as a $C^{\ast}$-algebra?

I believe it is not known what such a $G$ exists. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/466749/is-mathcalb-mathcalh-a-groupoid-c-algebra

Your title says "group" but your question says "groupoid". Which one do you mean? Also, what assumptions are you putting on your group(oid) - discrete? locally compact? etale? etc

Edited@Yemon Choi. Hope it is clear now.

Apologies (to @YemonChoi and @‍PKOA) for "group" in the title—I tried to edit to a more informative title, and didn't notice I'd changed "groupoid" to "group".

Well at least the question is consistent, but why do you think such a groupoid exists? And why have you combined the words in my comment when the combination you have chosen has some redundancy?

My apologies to the OP for not noticing that the error in the title was introduced by someone else.

@Yemon choi, for finite dimensional case it does exist just take matrix units, so I was curious as $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ has matrix units!!

@PKOA The issue is simply that the matrix units generate finite-dimensional matrix algebras as $C^\ast$-algebras, but only generate infinite-dimensional $B(H)$ as von Neumann algebras, and the latter is not enough to get a groupoid $C^\ast$-algebra structure. There’s also no other obvious choice, which is probably why this question is supposedly still open.

A groupoid C*-algebra $\mathrm{C}^\ast_{\mathrm{r}}G$ has a faithful conditional expectation $E$ onto the Cartan subalgebra (in the $\mathrm{C}^*$-sense) $C_0(G^{(0)})$. I guess faithfulness of $E$ (restricted to $K(H)$) implies $C_0(G^{(0)})$ atomic and $C_0(G^{(0)})$ cannot be a Cartan subalgebra. I haven't checked the detail. (The norm-closure of those $T$ on $\ell_2\mathbb{N}$ such that $\sup_i |{ j : |T_{i,j}|+|T_{j,i}|>0 }|<\infty$ is an etale groupoid $\mathrm{C}^\ast$-algebra, but it is strictly smaller than $B(\ell_2\mathbb{N})$.)

We know $L^{\infty}(X, \mu)$ is a cartan subalgebra of $\mathcal{B}(L^{2}(X, \mu)$  as a von Neumann algebra. Is that the same reason $C(X)$ may not be cartan in $\mathcal{B}(L^{2}(X, \mu))$(embedded as multiplication operator) in $C^{\ast}$ sense?

@NarutakaOZAWA I can see that the faithfulness of $E$ implies $C_0(G^{(0)})$ is atomic, assuming $C_0(G^{(0)})$ is actually a von Neumann subalgebra of $B(H)$ and $E$ is normal, by applying modular theory. But I don’t see how one would show this without normality assumption?

@David Gao: If a $\mathrm{C}^\ast$-algebra $A\subset B(H)$ is the range of a faithful conditional expectation $E$, then it is a von Neumann algebra. Indeed, if $a$ is the SOT-limit of a bounded increasing net $(a_i)$ in $A_+$, then $E(a) - a \geq 0$, because $E(a)\geq E(a_i)=a_i$ for all $i$, which implies $E(a) = a$ by faithfulness of $E$.

@NarutakaOZAWA Oh, that’s a great argument, thanks! Do you also know of a way around the normality issue? There certainly are faithful non-normal expectations, but it should always have a faithful normal part. The normal part is not automatically an expectation though. (And, for that matter, I’ve realized the argument I had in mind for when $E$ is normal is wrong. I’ve mistakenly assumed the modular automorphism group fixes $C_0(G^{(0)})$ pointwise, which it does not need to.)

@NarutakaOZAWA Ah, never mind, I’ve figured out the normality part. As long as a faithful expectation exists, a faithful normal expectation exists. So the only remaining issue is how to prove $C_0(G^{(0)})$ is atomic whenever a faithful normal expectation exists. I’d still assume some modular automorphism argument works…? But my knowledge of modular theory is quite limited.

@David Gao: "Do you also know of a way around the normality issue?" It should be obvious, but not to me...
